# nodemon: permission denied while deploying on render.com

Tags: nodemon, render.com

I get the following error in my logs while deploying with Render.com, what can I do?

[image: Render log Error message]

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

I wish to deploy my backend as a web service on Render.com It says like  this an error, I am looking for the successful deployment.

Comment: Why use nodemon in production anyway? What changes is it going to be watching for?

Answer (score 0):

The "start" in the scripts should be set differently for production than for development. Try the following:

1. You should change the script to:

   ```
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node app.js",
    },
   ```
2. Push the changes to github.com
3. Go back to the render dashboard and click "manual deploy", then select "deploy latest commit" from the dropdown menu.